# How to predict image size in megabytes after JPEG-compression

Tags: android, image-processing

For example, we have file.jpg with size 5Mb. And our aim is to compress it to size 2Mb. There is souch methodin SDK: Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream).

Is there any variant to calculate target quality value before compression?

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot predict the final output of JPEG compression.**

The only option for you would be to perform some brute forcing, but in an optimized way.

Generally JPEG compresses the bitmap in the ratio 10:1.

So if your image resolution is 4096*4096, it requires 4096*4096*2 raw bytes (2 because RGB_565 is used), which equals 33554432 bytes = 32MB raw. Assuming 10:1 compression, It will take 3.2MB.

But it is greater than 2MB! So you will need to make the quality to 2/3.2=62.5℅. So first try with 62℅ as a quality parameter.

Now compress the image to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and check the length of the byte array. If the length of the array is less than 2*1024*1024=2097152, it is okay. Otherwise you should try decreasing the quality eg by 10℅ to 52℅ and try again.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), quality is a int that Hint to the compressor, 0-100. When 0 meaning compress for small size and 100 meaning compress for max quality. But some formats like PNG which is lossless, will ignore this quality setting. So, i think it's depend on your goal. If you want to get the maximum quality in minimum size then you need to resize & implement high number of quality.

Hope, it can help you.

Comment: _"some formats like PNG which is lossless, will ignore this quality setting"_ The question is about JPEG specifically.